# Consulta sobre if javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy creando un codigo que me permita leer un objeto en este caso lee una variable llamada `autos` en un modulo y lo importa.

Luego lee la patente ingresada y busca que coincida con el objeto importado, entonces, si la patente ingresada es igual a la patente del objeto y la propiedad `vendido` es igual a `true`, me trae un resultado sino otro.

El punto es que primero me esta leyendo el `else` y luego me lee la función.

Cuando imprimo resultado por pantalla, me trae el resultado del `else` primero y luego me trae el valor que realmente deberia traer.

Les paso el codigo:

```
let readline = require('readline-sync');
let autos = require('./autos')


let pte = readline.question("Ingrese la patente: ");

function buscarAuto(autos){
    for (let i = 0; i< autos.length ; i++){
        if(pte == autos[i].patente && autos[i].vendido==true){
        console.log("auto vendido")
        }
        else if(pte == autos[i].patente && autos[i].vendido==false){
        console.log("Auto en venta");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Auto no encontrado")
        }
    }
}

buscarAuto(autos);
```

Como resultado me trae lo siguiente:

```
"Auto no encontrado
Auto en venta"
```

Cuando deberia traer:

```
"Auto en venta"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que por cada auto en el arrelgo de `autos` que controlas estas imprimiendo un mensaje.

Lo que deberías hacer es:

- Primero, buscar si existe un auto con la patente en el arreglo de `autos`.
- Una vez terminada la busqueda:

  - Si **NO** encontraste un auto con esa patente, mostrar mensaje `Auto no encontrado`.
  - Si encontraste un auto y esta `vendido`, mostrar mensaje `Auto  vendido`.
  - Sino, mostrar mensaje `Auto en venta`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function buscarAuto(autos) {
  let auto = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
    if (pte == autos[i].patente) {
      auto = autos[i];
      break; // Dejamos de buscar
    }
  }

  if (!auto) {
    console.log("Auto no encontrado");
  } else if (auto.vendido) {
    console.log("Auto vendido");
  } else {
    console.log("Auto en venta");
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!